# For every extra "x", add "y"

Tags: google-sheets

so I'm trying to make a function that adds "300" to "price" for every extra minute of duration of the task. For example, the base price of a task is 600 for 2 minutes. Make that 900 for 3 minutes, 1200 for 4 minutes, 1500 for 5 minutes, etc. Technically I can do that with `IF()` but that's not really practical since I'd have to make a lot of if functions. Thanks.

Comment: Please show sample data with desired output. What happends with 1 minute for example?

Comment: There's no sample data, I'll need to do this next week so I'm trying to figure out how to do it. I just need an idea, so I don't end up using "ifs". If it's 1 minute, then don't change the price. Everything up to 2 minutes is 600. Everything above is +300 for every minute.Don't worry about seconds, just think about whole minutes.

Comment: Is your data in actual timevalues, e.g.: `00:01` for one minute? etc.

Comment: Yes it is. However, If that's too hard/impossible, I'll just make a separate row for that and use minutes as int values, so it's ok.

Comment: Right, I forgot, I use the `VALUE()` function for my time, so it turns my minutes into seconds. So yeah, everything up to 120 is 600, every next 60 seconds, add 300.

Comment: Seems like pure math `=IF(A1<=120,600,(A1/60)*300)`

Comment: That works, however, I don't want values inbetween those 300 jumps. So if duration is 125, I don't want the price to be 625, but 900. As soon as it goes in the next minute, add it to the price as a full minute. Sorry if I was unclear. Hmm... I guess I'll have to use minutes for that, not seconds. Thanks, I'll accept your answer. Just post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you could use:

```
=IF(A1<=120,600,ROUNDUP(A1/60)*300)
```